# Best HMM Package

Tags: sequence, markov-hidden-model

What is the best HMM (Hidden Markov Model) library available in Python? I have already looked into seqlearn and hmmlearn, but both of them don't seem to be actively maintained.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen pomegranate .? http://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
and ghmm http://ghmm.org/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best nowadays but Mallet includes a good few algorithms for probabilistic learning, in particular sequence labeling methods: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu

Comment: But, mallet is in JAVA

Comment: Yes, what's wrong with that? the question doesn't specify any language.

Comment: yeah that is fine. Do you know any updated package in python.?